# How do I create an Agent model that can spans across Companies in a scope based multi tenancy app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've built a multi-tenancy app that has `User` & `Report` that belong to a `Company` as shown below, (multi tenancy app using company_id to scope everything else - Users & Reports).

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reports
    has_many :users
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :reports
end
```

report.rb

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :company
end
```

I now wish to add an `Agency` model (with `agency_users`) that will enable the to manage multiple companies (and that companies reports). The Agent will need to be able to switching from one company two another.

How would I approach this? Agent has many Companies

```
class Agent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :companies
end
```

I can't quite work out how the agent would switch between the company_ids in order to view the reports for the companies it is responsible (it's clients).

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to highlight the fact I was referring to the models within a sentence. Thanks for the edit advice though, i've updated it now. :)

Comment: Use coding style provided by SO (bold, italic etc.) to highlight words/sentences.

Comment: Do u have `agencies` table schema prepared?

Comment: An `agency` would just have `agency_name` (like a real life agency) and maybe some other params - not confirmed yet sorry. An `agency` would also have_many `agents` that belong_to it (which would be an separate devise users).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, here's a solution that can be helpful

```
class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies
  has_many :users
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reports
    belongs_to :agency
end

class Users < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reports
    belongs_to :agency
    enum role: [:agent]
end
```

Now, when the user signs in to your app, show him a dropdown of which company he's currently controlling. Store this `id` in a session and use it to query your data:

`current_user.reports.where(company_id: session[:company_id].to_i)` for example;

Same goes to creating and deleting them.

However, this is not the optimal solution (I'm not sure what your intentions are).

I would go with something more general, like user roles for each company with `UserCompany` having `company`, `user` and `role` instead of the `role` on the user level (maybe he's an agent at a company but admin another company; etc...). All of that varies based on what you really need to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer Roc! I was planning on having a Agency model that the Company belongs_to as well as Agents (effectively AgencyUsers - ppl who work at the agency which are different from the Company and Users). Will that still work with the approach you mentioned above?

Comment: @aymorgan I've edited the answer and stated that it's not the perfect one to go with; it's based on your needs..